# Accessing the value from usercontrol in windows app

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a `usercontrol` called `AddRow` and a `form` called `TimeSheet` ,`Timesheet` has a `save_btn` event, on click of `save_btn` the value enter in `usercontrol` should be written to database,but I am not able to access the value from `usercontrol`

below is the code

```
public void save_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlCommand cmdinsert = new SqlCommand("insert into TimeSheet (Project_Name,Activity_Name, Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday) values (@Project_Name,@Activity_Name, @Monday,@Tuesday,@Wednesday,@Thursday,@Friday,@Saturday,@Sunday) ", con);
        cmdinsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Project_Name", add.project_cbox.SelectedIndex);
        cmdinsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Activity_Name", activity_cb.SelectedIndex);
        cmdinsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Monday", add.monday_txt_val);
        cmdinsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tuesday", add.tuesday_txt_val);
        cmdinsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Wednesday", add.wednesday_txt.Text);
        cmdinsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Thursday", add.thursday_txt.Text);
        cmdinsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Friday", add.friday_txt.Text);
        cmdinsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Saturday", add.saturday_txt.Text);
        cmdinsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sunday", add.sunday_txt.Text);
        con.Open();
        cmdinsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();  

    }
```

this event is in `timesheet` but the value is empty string...I just cant access the value,is there a solution? this is window application

```
 public string monday_txt_val
    {
        get
        {
            return monday_txt.Text;
        }

        set
        {
            monday_txt.Text = value;
        }
    }
```

`monday_txt` is a  `textbox` that is created dynamically,after the value is entered ,but it is reading a empty string,despite me entering a value in `textbox`,when it is passed to `form` value of `monday_txt` is empty string,how to fix this?

only way I can think of accessing `monday_txt` is by creating a instance of `AddRow` in `Timesheet`..but When new instance is created I will not be able to get the value, kindly help

Comment: >  but the value is null - what value is null? What do you mean under `I just cant access the value`?

Comment: @Dennis-When I enter a value in the `textbox` which is in `usercontrol` the entered value is not saved int the database,the value in `monday_txt` is null ,no value is written into `monday_txt` despite me entering some value in the `textbox`

Comment: @Dennis-any help? when i create a button event in the `usercontrol` it works fine but when the button_click is from the `form` it is not writing the value into database

Answer (score 0):

OK, so first you say you create the textbox dynamically, BUT after the value is entered.. I dont understand. Then were do you enter the value if you haven't created the textbox yet. That's 1. 2 can you try like a Response.Write on button click(I use web forms so I don't know how you can debug) to see if you have anything at all in your textbox. If you have and it doesn't show, then first try to set the textbox by code.. to see if you have access to it at all. Also if you create the textbox dynamically then look where you are creating it. if its not inside the form ellement you can't reach it. That's all I can think of. You need to have more details and show more code than this.